# How to wait for state to not be undefiened in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

With this code on the component mount, there is a bug where *priceToDisplay* is first set as undefined, and it won't change state until some part of the component is not rerendered. If I remove that const from the dependencie array in useEffect, the correct value will be set.

```
 const [isOnDiscount, setIsOnDiscount] = useState(
        parseInt(product_data.discount_price && product_data.discount_price) !== 0
      );
      const [priceToDisplay, setPriceToDisplay] = useState(
        isOnDiscount ? product_data.discount_price : product_data.price_of_product
      );

  useEffect(() => {
    const isOnDiscountEffect = parseInt(product_data.discount_price) !== 0;
    const priceToDisplayEffect = 0;
    console.log(priceToDisplay);

    if (isOnDiscountEffect) {
      setPriceToDisplay(product_data.discount_price);
    } else if (doesVariationAffectPrice()) {
      // price of variation
    } else {
      setPriceToDisplay(product_data.price_of_product);
    }
  }, [priceToDisplay]);
```

Comment: where is `product_data` coming from? Props? It would help if you post the whole component. But in general, if product_data is undefined in the beginning, it is useless to use it as a default value for `useState(<defaultValue>)`. What is the reason you are putting it into the state variable after all?

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to tell without knowing the whole component, but I assume that you are trying to do something like this:

```
export const Simple = ({product_data}) => {

  const [priceToDisplay, setPriceToDisplay] = useState(null);

  const isOnDiscount = parseInt(product_data.discount_price) !== 0;


  useEffect(() => {

    if (isOnDiscount) {
      setPriceToDisplay(product_data.discount_price);
    } else if (doesVariationAffectPrice()) {
      // price of variation
    } else {
      setPriceToDisplay(product_data.price_of_product);
    }
  }, [isOnDiscount]);

  return <div>
    {priceToDisplay}
  </div>

};
```

you dont need a state variable for `isOnDiscount`for that.